How to specify the version of the built deb package in the format brahch-commit-timedelta?
How to specify the version of the built deb package in the format
brahch-commit-timedelta
$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA-$(date +%s)
In the documentation of DEBIAN/control I see that there is a Version field that must begin with numbers.In the documentation I see that there is a Version field that should start with numbers, but this is not what is needed for software development. What are the practices for indicating the software version in the format I specified?
